# Why am I getting the second digit only here?

Tags: python

Both text files have an ever-increasing value. When the value is greater than 9 for either of them, the code uses and prints out only the ones place for that number. How do I fix that issue?

```
h = open('which-quotea.txt', 'r')
content = h.readline()  # Reading from the file
var_a = 0
for line in content:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit() == True:
# Checking for the digit in the string
            var_a = int(i)
print(var_a)
h.close()
h = open('which-quoteb.txt', 'r')
content = h.readline()  # Reading from the file
var_b = 1
for line in content:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit() == True:
# Checking for the digit in the string
            var_b = int(i)
print(var_b)
h.close()
```

Comment: I do not see where you check for greater than 9.

Comment: In your own words, when you do `for i in line:`, what values are you expecting `i` to have? What do you expect to happen to `var_a` (or `var_b` each time through the loop? It seems that you intend for the final value to account for all the digits in the number. How do you intend for your program's logic to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

For `numbers > 9`, `var_a` or `var_b` should be updated as `var_a=var_a*10+var_a`, `var_b=var_b*10+var_b.`

Answer (score 0):

First change `readline` to `readlines`.

And `i` in `for i in line:` is each characters in line.

e.g.

```
line='123 456'
for i in line:
    print(i)
# '1'
# '2'
# '3'
# ' '
# '4'
# '5'
# '6'
```

Use `split()` or something other method.

```
list(map(int, line.split()))
# [123, 456]
```